# Mongoose 1.0.2 not connecting to repl.it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js, replit

So my problem is that I am hosting a discord bot on repl.it and It is refusing to connect to mongo db on my laptop I have tried to create a account but I don't know how to connect it. I have been trying to connect it for almost 2 weeks now and I tried to find the answers on YouTube and google but no use. I am using mongoose version 1.0.2. any help would be apricated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us any code you tried, describe what did you try, or any error you've got.

Comment: You did not give us any code, next time can you please give us a code snippet? That will help a lot Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

umm are you using cloud db?
if not use it for syncing between pc and repl it